# Get Random SKU Product Number

Tags: magento

I have the following code:

```
$sku = $id; 
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); //Get Product by ID (ASIN)
$qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); //if in stock
$_prodcats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```

It works by specfing the SKU id, I want to be able to get random SKU product number and use it so

```
$sku = random product number from database
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following script to generate a random sku from the collection. You can use it to suit your requirement also.

```
//Geting a random sku from collection

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
$randomSku = $collection->setPage(1, 1)->getFirstItem()->getSKU();
```

In your case your code should look like.......

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
$_product = $collection->setPage(1, 1)->getFirstItem()->load();

$qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); //if in stock
$_prodcats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```

Comment: you're the best thanks a lot for the random Sku number I needed that very much!

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work fine ;)

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel(‘catalog/product_collection’);
Mage::getModel(‘catalog/layer’)->prepareProductCollection($collection);
$collection->getSelect()->order(‘rand()’);
$collection->addStoreFilter();
$collection->setPage(1, 1);
$_product = $collection->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: Thank you Kuba It's exactly what I need Is it possible to get the SKU of that random product that was selected? for later use :)

Comment: or even better a code to get a random SKU number from database will help me much more!

Comment: $sku = $collection->getFirstItem()->getSku();

for better performance you can get all product ids form collection and get random index from array. But it make sense when you have lot of products in database :)

Answer (score 0):

Below code I used in project and its working fine for me :

```
<?php 

    // get Random prdocut list
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel(‘catalog/product_collection’);
    Mage::getModel(‘catalog/layer’)->prepareProductCollection($collection);
    $collection->getSelect()->order(‘rand()’);
    $collection->addStoreFilter();
    $numProducts = $this->getNumProducts() ? $this->getNumProducts() : 2;
    $collection->setPage(1, $numProducts);

    foreach($collection as $product){

    echo $product->getName();

    }
?>
```